# When to use Meta on Stack Exchange and when on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta

There are two meta sites that contains content related to the main Stack Overflow site: http://meta.stackoverflow.com and http://meta.stackexchange.com

If I have a question about Stack Overflow (privileges, bans, suggestions) which meta site is more adequate to ask it on and why?

Maybe more general question is what is difference between those two meta sites (except of that http://meta.stackexchange.com is also for other Stack Exchange sites)?
I had a look on [what topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are on-topic on Meta Stack Exchange and [what topic s](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are on Meta Stack Overflow. But the second one shows info about the main Stack Overflow site, not just meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a problem/question about a specific site, you should ask it on the site's own meta. These topics might require at least a basic understanding of that site's topic (e.g. to know what is in and out of the scope of that site). *Here*, on Meta Stack Exchange, you ask questions which are *not* related to a specific site.

So, for example privileges: if you want to know at which reputation level you get a certain privilege on Stack Overflow, it should go to Meta Stack Overflow. If you want a comparison between different site, you can ask it here (except for that that questions already [exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)).

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about anything *specific* to Stack Overflow as on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). The same holds for every per-site meta. Examples are questions about specific questions, specific reviews, on-topic policy or anything that is specific to that community.

If your question is about anything that affects the entire Stack Exchange network then ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Questions about privileges in general for example or feature requests should mostly be posted on MSE.